# Visa Checkout Cordova Plugin

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, cordova-plugins, appcelerator-titanium, cordova-cli

The Visa Checkout SDK is available for native apps (iOS & Android). 
Where can i find the Visa Checkout Cordova plugin for integrating into hybrid mobile apps ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you would probably use the Visa Checkout Javascript SDK:

https://github.com/visa/SampleCode/wiki/Visa-Checkout

Comment: I tried to run the html page on my local machine, but i didnt receive any call back like payment error or payment cancel. I also found this message in the Sample code description "The page to which you are adding a Visa Checkout button must be hosted on a web server for the lightbox and JavaScript library to perform as expected."